# How to make developed features like Google Street view in my own site

Tags: asp.net

I would like to develop an application using google street. I will upload images in my application. The users of my application will then be able to view the uploaded images like google street. like we can see images in the link below 
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/11/introducing-street-view-and-photo.html

How can i develop like this.?
can you please help me?

Comment: I have been able to embed google map in my website

Comment: I have been able to embed google map in my website now i want to upload my own images so that those images can be used in google map so that my uploaded images can be viewd like we see in the google map image street view.